# How to load message in real time to a viewer in MVC 4 framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a MVC 4 .NET/C# project to do data loading automatically. When insert new record to database, I want to display a line of message in the viewer in real time. So it would be something like

```
Record 1 has been loaded successfully!
Record 2 has been loaded successfully!
Record 3 has been loaded successfully!
Record 4 has been loaded successfully!
....
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Signalr is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Of course. First at all you should write a method which returns numer of records. On the loading page you can use that method to receive number of records f.ex:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CountRecords()
{
    int records = repository.CountRecords();
    return JavaScript(SimpleJsonSerializer.Serialize(records.ToString());
}

public ActionResult LoadRecord(int number)
{
    repository.LoadRecord(number);
    return JavaScript(SimpleJsonSerializer.Serialize("Success");
}
```

.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "@Url.Action("CountRecords", "Controller")",
        success: function (response) {
            var rows = response.replace('\"', '');
            for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: i,
                    url: "@Url.Action("LoadRecord", "Controller")",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var status = response.replace('\"', '');
                        if (status == 'Success')
                        $('.messages').append('Record ' + i + ' has been loaded successfully!');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Of course it would take more time than in 1 call to controller, but it will works. I don't know if there is possibility to make realtime interface without calling controller many times.
Saving items can be done same as loading.
Regards.